# How to write a function within a stored procedure in DB2

Tags: db2

I am able to write a separate stored procedure and separate function in DB2.
I want to write a function within a stored procedure in DB2.

Please provide an example.

Please note I don't want any example to create a stored procedure and function separate and call the function from the stored procedure.

Comment: If you mean SQL-PL procedures, you cannot do that exactly.   A Db2 user-defined function (UDF) must be a separate object from an SQL-PL stored procedure, although can be created in the same script. However, you can create a "local procedure" (as in, a stored procedure defined within another SQL-PL stored procedure. DIFFERENT options are available to stored-procedures that are __not__ written in SQL-PL, for example, in c/c++, rexx, java etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a stored procedure inside a function and inside a stored procedure.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

create or replace FUNCTION outer_fn (
 ) returns integer
 begin
  declare in_val integer;
  declare out_val integer;

  declare procedure inner_sp (
    in in_val integer,
    out out_val integer)
   begin
    set out_val = in_val + 1;
   end;
  set in_val = 1;
  call inner_sp(in_val, out_val);
  return out_val;
 end@

values outer_fn@

create or replace PROCEDURE outer_sp (
  out out_val integer
 )
 begin
  declare in_val integer;

  declare procedure inner_sp (
    in in_val integer,
    out out_val integer
   )
   begin
    set out_val = in_val + 1;
   end;

  set in_val = 1;

  call inner_sp (in_val, out_val);
 end
@

call outer_sp(?)
@
```

I am not sure, but I think it is not possible to define a function inside a procedure or inside a function.

For more details, you can check this procedure that performs a recursion inside another stored procedure.

https://github.com/angoca/log4db2/blob/21eabc98e9e11a4c6486b5eee17e919d99bb2f66/src/main/sql-pl/06-GET_LOGGER.sql#L142

Finally, you can also create a module, with a published stored procedure that calls an "added" stored procedure / function in the same module. The "added" object is not visible / available outside the module.